# How to save file in internal storage in device

Tags: android, file, internal-storage

I am going with the download of files from the browser and stored in the internal storage of my device and the path appears as like **/data/data/com.example/files/downloads/sample.pdf**
but on next day i get the file path as empty **""**

using below code to save the file from browser:

```
    private String downloadfile(Uri uri) {
        int count;
        String fileName = "";
        try {
            // Output stream to write file
            String root = null;
//          if (Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable())

//          else
                root = getFilesDir().toString()+ "/download/";

            File file = new File(root);
            if (!file.exists())
                file.mkdirs();
            fileName = file.getAbsolutePath();

            file = new File("" + uri);
            fileName = fileName + "/" + file.getName();

            URL url = new URL(uri.toString());
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/octet-stream");
            conection.setRequestProperty("Expect", "100-continue");
            conection.setRequestProperty("Content-Disposition", "attachment");
            conection.setRequestProperty("filename", file.getName());
            conection.connect();

            // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            file = new File(fileName);
            file.createNewFile();
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            String inputs = "EX";
            Parameter.trackApplication(inputs, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return fileName;
    }
```

How can i solve this problem,please correct me where i am going wrong and help me out to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you check in other device whether it will return the path or not?

Comment: @DhruvVaishnav yes did check it but it returns empty path

Comment: @DhruvVaishnav is there any other way to save the file permanently